# Java Use string as object call

Tags: java, string, object

Good Afternoon,
i would like to ask regarding the methods to use string as reference.

Let say, that i got two object of type `LinkedList` named `ChinaShip` and `HongkongShip`

Normally, if i wanted to access a method (for example `getFirst()`)
i will type `ChinaShip.getFirst()`

Now, let say that in other object, i got a variable `Destination` which content is a String.
The example of the Content will be `China` and `Hongkong`

Is it possible to use the content of the variable as the name for accessing the LinkedList object?

my approach first would be concatenate the variable first, which will be `Destination + "Ship"`

This will produce a `string` which is `ChinaShip` and `HongkongShip`

The reason i'm doing this way rather than comparing the string is that the `Destination` consist of hundreds of posibilities.

Thank You Very Much.

Regards,

Comment: No, but you could use a `Map` of some kind

Comment: u may try [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put%28K,%20V%29) or [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) where u can store info in key=value pair

Comment: looks like it will do. Thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't do that in Java. But this is closer with that:

```
HashMap<String, LinkedList> dest = new HashMap<String, LinkedList>();
dest.put("China", ChinaShip);
dest.put("Hongkong", HongkongShip);
.....

if(dest.containsKey(Destination){
    dest.get(Destination).getFirst();
}
```

Comment: This is exactyly what i need to do. Thanks Sire :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use the reflection API. If the lists are declared in the class MyClass you can use the following code:

```
LinkedList list = (LinkedList) MyClass.class.getDeclaredField(Destination + "Ship").get(this);
```

This assumes that the above code is called from within a MyClass object, otherwise the `get(this)` call must be changed to `get(myClassInstance)`. Though as MadProgrammer mentions, you might be better of using a Map.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Map and use the desitnation string as your key because these will be unique:

```
Map<Desitnation, value> destinations = new HashMap<Desitnation, value>();
```

then search through the Map for your destination key:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/hashmap_get.htm

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to re-work your architecture. You shouldn't have to create method names from Strings.

It seems to me like you need a Ship object which has a destination, and a linkedlist of Ships.

If you need to map ships by destination, what you can also do is have a Map where they key is the destination string, and the value is the linked list of ships going to that destination.

So if you do a map.get("China") you will get a list of ships going to China, and from there you can do what you want.

Comment: Yeah thats exactly what i need to do. Thanks a lot sir, i'll try doing that.